# Linking error in C++ Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, linker, 32bit-64bit

I am new to C++ Boost library.

I already installed Boost 1.51 at BoostPro Computing website, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions (at two different folders (boost_1_51 and boost_1_51_x64).

I tried to use Visual Studio 2005 SP2 (on 32-bit Windows OS) to build for x64 and got the following errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

I did the library linking in project configuration (boost paths for additional include and library directories). For example:

> **include**: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51_x64\
>
> **library**: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51_x64\lib

Can anyone can help me figure out the linking error as above?

Comment: You should show the source code that produce the error. My guess is that, while you did set the default paths for includes and libraries, you didn't add the library's .LIB file itself in the VC++ project. I believe autolinking is enabled on Boost by default on Windows, but I'm not 100% sure, and it would explain your problem...

Comment: Are you sure that the boost libs you installed were built with MSVC8?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I solved the problem by re-installing the boost library (64-bit version). Maybe there were some errors during my last installation.

Comment: That worked for me too. (This time I was using boostpro, and included debug packages too.) I have no idea what was the problem previously.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments above:

> I solved the problem by re-installing the boost library (64-bit version). Maybe there were some errors during my last installation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by manually adding "boost_system-vc120-mt-1_61.lib" (your version will be different) to the project. I was using the prebuilt windows binaries https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/